# Drools ignores the rest of rules if one of rules didn't pass

Tags: drools

I'm starting a project with Drools. My project's drl file looks like:

```
rule "Rule 1"
when
    Item( id > 100)
// consequence implementation

rule "Rule 2"
when
    Item( type == "phone")
// consequence implementation

rule "Rule 3"
when
    Item( screenSize == 5)
// consequence implementation

rule "Rule 4"
when
    Item( branch == "motorola")
// consequence implementation

rule "Rule 5"
when
    Item( price > 200)
// consequence implementation
```

When Drools runs I have 5 fired rules. If an item don't pass one of 5 fire rules, I want Drools will ignore the rest 4 fired rules. Does Drools have feature for my purpose?

Another important thing is my Drools runs with AgendaFilter. Does that feature have AgendaFilter support?

Comment: I fail to understand your last paragraph. What is an "All-rules case", and your filter example is unclear.

Comment: All-rules case is Drools runtime will fire 5 rules if item match condition. When I use AgendaFilter allow only "Rule 1" "Rule 2" "Rule 3", Drools will check item with only ["Rule 1", "Rule 2", "Rule 3"]

Comment: As you say: what you call "All-rules case" and using an AgendaFilter blocking one or more of these rules is *not the same*. Once more, rules that are permitted to fire (by a filter) will fire, **as much and as many as they can** unless you add constraints, e.g., as noted in my answer.

Comment: Sorry! My unclear question leads you to mismatch. I updated my question. Not "If no rule should fire unless all rules can fire". Say when 5 rules are fired, first and second are passed, but 3rd fired rule is not passed. I want Drools ignore 4th and 5th fired rule.

Comment: Again, this comment indicates that you think that rules are handled in the order they appear on the DRL file. **This is not the case!** See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, the phrase in the title "rest of rules" seems to indicate that you think that the rules are evaluated in a certain order (e.g. as written in the file). This is not so: there is no order. Thus, if rules #1 and #2 fired (`ìd > 0` and `type == "phone"`) and `screenSize != 5`, rules #4 and rules #5 will still fire, or **they may already have been fired**.

To discover whether some fact whose class is referenced in rules 1 to 5 participates in all or some or none of these rules you'll have to create some logic of your own. For instance, declare a type/class with

```
class Marker { 
  Set<Integer> rules;
  TheClassOfYourItem item;
  //...
}
```

and insert this along with an item. Each rule would then, when firing, add its number to the set.

rule "Rule 1"
   when
       $item: TheClassOfYourItem(...)
       $m: Marker( item == $item )
   then
       $m.add( 1 );
   end

And a rule with low salience can then check whether the set has all/some/none elements.

**Edit** due to some comment: If no rule should fire unless all rules can fire: simply put all conditions into a single rule and combine all consequences.

```
rule "Rule 1-5"
when
    Item( id > 100, type == "phone". screenSize == 5,
          branch == "motorola", price > 200)
then
    // ... Do what needs to be done if all five conditions are true
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't care about order of rules. An valid item must pass 5 rules. If an item doesn't pass any of 5 rules, I want Drools won't fire the rest 4 rules.

Comment: If you don't want to fire no rule unless you can fire *all* rules you'll have to write one rule that fire when one of the rules will *not* fire and try to fire these rules before the original rules. Or you can write *one* rule combining the conditions of all five rules and use just this single rule.